# Get all squares in a given area

Tags: java, sqlite, find, area

[image]

Image explanation:
I want to get all the grey boxes in in the blue area, but not the ones outside

The center dot is at x,z location and the blue border is x radius from the center dot

This is the sqlite query to check if location is inside a claim

```
SELECT uuid,world,x1,z1,x2,z2 FROM `claims` WHERE %s = `world` AND x >= `x1` AND z >= `z1` AND x < `x2` AND z < `z2` LIMIT 1
```

This is my find method:

```
public static List<Claim> find(Location loc, int radius) throws Exception {
    int x1 = loc.getBlockX() + radius, z1 = loc.getBlockZ() + radius;
    int x2 = loc.getBlockX() - radius, z2 = loc.getBlockZ() - radius;
    List<Row> rows = database.getRows(String.format("SELECT uuid,world,x1,z1,x2,z2 FROM `claims` WHERE %s = `world` AND /*TODO find solution*/", loc.getWorld().getName()));
    List<Claim> claims = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Row r : rows) {
        World w = Bukkit.getWorld(UUID.fromString("world"));
        claims.add(new Claim(UUID.fromString(r.getString("uuid")), new Location(w, r.getInt("x1"), 0, r.getInt("z1")), new Location(w, r.getInt("x2"), 0, r.getInt("z2"))));
    }
    return claims;
}
```

Checking each location for a claim isn't really efficient and looking in larger radius could even cause massive lag

Table

[image]

Comment: Can you include a few records from the `claims` table so that we may see what it looks like?  Would one record correspond to a single gray square?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated the post

Comment: You probably want to use an [R-tree](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html).

Comment: @CL I realized that I only need to check if one of the values is inside a given area resulting in this: ```((`x1` >= %d AND `z1` >= %d) OR (`x2` >= %d AND `z2` >= %d)) AND ((`x1` < %d AND `z1` < %d) OR (`x2` < %d AND `z2` < %d))``` but is r-tree faster?